# how to filter products details using in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I am developing an application where there are two models: mobile `Brand` and mobile `Product`. Every brand `has_many :products`.

In the index page I am showing all the products and left side I want to show ranges like other shopping card, for example:

> Search by Price
>
> - 10000-15000
> - 15000-20000
> - 20000-25000
> - Prices > 25,000
>
> Search by RAM
>
> - 256 mb
> - 512 mb
>
> Search by Cam
>
> - 13 MP
> - 8 MP
> - 5 MP
>
> Search by Screen
>
> - Less Then 3 Inches
> - 3.0 inch - 4.0 inch
> - 4.1 inch - 4.9 inch

Like this I want to show when click any link it will show that details.

so please help me how to write in product controller, it need to create different action in controller and different view page.
so give me few code idea how to do it.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to ask for the code you wish.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scopes to solve this problem. I will show you how to filter with a price range and i believe the same process can be used for other filters.

Have this in your `product` model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  ## other code
  scope :price_min, lambda{|min| where(['price >= ?', min])}
  scope :price_max, lambda{|max| where(['price <= ?', max])}
  ## other code
end
```

in `products_controller.rb` have this:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  has_scope :price_min
  has_scope :price_max

  def index
   @products = Product.all
  end

  ## other code
end
```

in your `app/views/products/index.html.erb` have this:

```
<%= link_to '10000-15000', @products_path, price_min: 10000, price_max: 15000 %>
<%= link_to '15000-20000', @products_path, price_min: 15000, price_max: 20000 %>
<%= link_to '20000-25000', @products_path, price_min: 20000, price_max: 25000 %>
```

**EDIT:**
Also ensure you have this in your Gemfile

```
gem 'has_scope'
```

and then run the bundle command.

Comment: what you have written its help full for me but not working in my app, when click any price range link its showing all product price instead of price range.

Comment: @Alok I forgot to add that you need the `has_scope` gem in your gemfile. Check the updated answer and try the example one more time.

Comment: before that I had already used has_scope gem, but not working not going to other page or anything please help me how to solve it @pette  thanks again.